# Is this circuit possible?

Tags: arduino, motor, circuit-design

I am making an electrical circuit for a school project, yet electrical engineering skills cease after Ohm's law :) Now I did some research but I find electric circuits harder to design than I had expected.

For the project, we need to control 6 12 V DC motors. We found that 4 of these motors need 1.2 A and 2 need 0.2 A. We control these motors with an Arduino, this Arduino needs 0.04 A. Motors and Arduino are powered separately by a 12 V DC transformer with max 5.83 A.

Since the motors need to rotate CW and CCW, a Dual H-Bridge DC Stepper Motor Driver - L298N is used and this driver drops the voltage by 2 V (from 12V input to 10 V output):

https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-dc-motor-control-tutorial-l298n-pwm-h-bridge/

The circuit I made is here:

[image: Circuit]

Now my question is: Is this a viable circuit or have I overlooked / misunderstood something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider if you do not have a slow start control on current, the surge current is 10x max rated power. or 100x the idle no-load power at rated speed.  So get mo-power  (from Toronto)  Measuring the motor DCR will tell you this.. Similar for light bulbs

Comment: Why have you connected your arduino in parallel with the Door Motors? Is the Door Motor Driver intended to switch the arduino's power on and off??

Comment: H bridge can be represented by 4 SPST switches ... it may help you to revise your schematic

Comment: Edit the schematics, use block as Arduino, use another block for the H-bridge - it shall have supply inputs (2) and two outputs (motor), and so on. I can't understand what the Arduino is in series with a motor and where is the H-bridge.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I got some real new (basic) knowledge out of this :)

Answer (score 1):

You meant, something like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH1JEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Aaahh it makes much more sense now. I do have three drivers but that wouldn't matter for but for the current. Thanks alot Marko!

Comment: @Martijn1002 Edited for 3 motor drivers, you can edit copy/paste from my answer. Still, I don't understand what is your main question?